# SQL Select statment, Set FieldA to 0 IF FieldB = ABC

Tags: sql, select

I need to set the value of fieldA = 0 IF FieldB = ABC

```
select *,
case when FIELDB = 'ABC' then FIELDA = '0' else FIELDA END 
from Table1
```

Comment: What means *set the value*? Do you mean update in the database or only in the result of the select?

Comment: How about: 
`   select new_col, table1.*
        select *,
        case when FIELDB = 'ABC' then '0' 
        else FIELDA 
     END as new_col
    from Table1 `

Then just drop/replace the old `FIELDA` with new_col?

Comment: Hi, just as the result of the select, I can't use a new field because when FieldB is not ABC and i don't want the value to change

Comment: question is kinda ambiguous ... you need to help us understand whether you're writing a select or an update statement. maybe provide some sample data for your table, and a sample result set.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to modify a value, you must use `update` sentence instead `select`. Try with:

`update Table1 set FIELDA = '0' where FIELDB = 'ABC'`

I think the sentence is self-explanatory

Comment: Hi, i don't want to update the table, just the result when i run select

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
    ,CASE WHEN fieldB = 'ABC' THEN 0 ELSE fieldA END AS fieldA
FROM Tabel1
```